# Recurrence equation

Tags: javascript, math

This is the formula I use to figure out the cost.

```
var increment = 0.001
var starting_price = 10
var cost = starting_price / increment * (Math.pow(increment + 1, quantity) - 1)
```

It's a recurrence equation.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%29%20%3Dc%20%28d%2B1%29%5En%2C%20f%280%29%20%3D%200%2C%20f%28n%29%20%3D%20f%28n-1%29%20%2B%20g%28n-1%29

What is a formula to figure out if you have 10,000 dollars how many can you purchase?

Comment: `Math.floor(total_money / price_for_each)` comes to mind ?

Comment: Could you add more parentheses to make it clearer what order of operations you expect?  I'd especially like you to clarify the left of the `*` and of the `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

quantity = log( base= d + 1, number = 10 000 * increment / starting_price + 1)

which in terms of your example gives

quantity = log( base= 0.001 + 1, number = 10 000 * 0.001 / 10 + 1)

quantity = log( base= 1.001, number = 2) = **693.4936964169**

http://www.calculator.net/log-calculator.html?yv=&xv=2&base=o&otherbase=1.001&x=83&y=7